# Initializing object members inside constructor

Tags: c++

I was recently working on classes in C++ and I found out I can not initialize objects inside constructor. Let me explain:

```
class Rect {
public:
    Rect(float x, float y): m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
    float area() {return m_x*m_y;}
private: 
    float m_x;
    float m_y;
};

class Cube{
public:
    Cube(float x, float y, float z) {
        m_r = new Rect(z,y);  //This is not possible.. but why not?
        m_z = z;
    }
    float volume() {return m_r.area()*z;}
private:
    Rect m_r;
    float m_z;
};
```

To solve this, I can either do 
`Cube(float x, float y, float z) : m_r(x,y), m_z(z) {}` or change `m_r` to a pointer and then assign the value
`m_r = new Rect(x,y)` How can I set the value without changing `m_r` to be a pointer and assign its value inside the constructor body?

Comment: `new` returns a pointer and `m_r` isn't one. But the reason you can't initialize members in the constructor body is that by that stage they have already been initialized.

Comment: _"This is not possible.. but why not?"_ Why would it be? o.O C++ != Java

Comment: wow, what a rude comment here, what if I'm coming from managed languages having more than 15 years of experience and just wanted to jump into c++? not so cool. Also, why the negatives to this well presented question? I came here with the same doubt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, you want to assign to `m_z` in the body of the constructor instead of initializing it, you need to do two things:

1) Give `Rect` a default constructor. It needs it because `m_z` will get default initialized.

2) Assign thus: `m_r = Rect(z,y);`

Comment: ah thanks, so all I needed to do was add a default empty constructor because of `Rect m_r;` could not find a empty constructor... now I understand what the problem was :D

Comment: @yoyo: But it's better not to do this. _Initialise_ `m_r` instead.

Comment: @yoyoburger Well, the `new` thing is also a problem. Even if it compiled it would most likely result in a memory leak. But it doesn't make much sense to assign if you can initialize.